# How can I wait for all async functions to be completed in useEffect before updating loading state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to receive a list of book IDs from my API. For each book ID, I want to fetch its data from Google's book API. Once all book info has been retrieved, I want to render divs for them. However, the loading state is being changed before each fetch has completed. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

```
function ReadingListPage({ userID }) {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  let bookIds = [];

  useEffect(() => {

    const getBookInfo = async (bookId) => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/${bookId}`);
      const resJson = await response.json();
      setBooks([...books, resJson]);
      Promise.resolve();
    };

    const getBookIds = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`//localhost:3001/user/reading_list/${userID}`);
      const resJson = await response.json();
      bookIds = resJson;

      await Promise.all(
        bookIds.map(async (bookId) => {
          await getBookInfo(bookId);
        })
      );

      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    getBookIds();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ContentLayout>
      <BookDisplay>
        {!isLoading && <BookSection name={"Your Reading List"} books={books}></BookSection>}
      </BookDisplay>
    </ContentLayout>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not showing before all books have loaded. It's just that you're overriding your books. I'd try to rewrite it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getBookInfo = async (bookId) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/${bookId}`);
    const book = await response.json();
    return book;
  };

  const getBookIds = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`//localhost:3001/user/reading_list/${userID}`);
    const resJson = await response.json();
    bookIds = resJson;

    const books = await Promise.all(bookIds.map(async (bookId) => getBookInfo(bookId)));

    setBooks(books);

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  getBookIds();
}, []);
```

This way, you only set the new value to books once and don't override it.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I have a question though, why are the books getting overwrote?

Comment: I don't know how to go into too much details, but the basic idea is: this function in run once within the same scope. Once you use `setBooks` the **next** render will have the new books. So all of these books will have access to the same empty array, ignoring the changes that were made because they will be applied on the next cycle

Answer (score 0):

try this code i hope usefull for you

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ...

  const getBookInfo = async (bookId) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/${bookId}`);
    const resJson = await response.json();
    setBooks(prevBooks => [...prevBooks, resJson]);
  };

  // ...
}, []);
```